# RoR ffmpeg installed by brew

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ffmpeg, carrierwave, homebrew

I'm developing a Ruby on Rails application that needs ffmpeg, to do some processing of the files I have.

However, when trying to use ffmpeg, I get this error

```
Failed encoding. Errors: no output file created. Full output: dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libogg.0.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
Reason: Incompatible library version: ffmpeg requires version 9.0.0 or later, but libogg.0.dylib provides version 6.0.0
```

It's a basically a CarrierWave project, which can be seen here: http://www.freezzo.com/2010/12/23/create-ffmpeg-processor-for-carrierwave-in-rails-3/

Comment: How is this programming related? You should ask the brew mailing list (if such a thing exists).

Comment: Well, it's configuration mangement. Which surely is programming related. My suspesion is that it's brew that does something wrong, but I don't have anything to prove it, and therefor it might also be programming related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you have an outdated version of libogg you should try a

```
brew update && brew upgrade libogg

$ otool -L /usr/local/lib/libogg.0.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libogg.0.dylib:
    /usr/local/lib/libogg.0.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```